# ShowParameterPrompt property not working in SSRS ReportViewer API

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2019

I'm trying to enable ShowParametersPrompt in the SSRS ReportViewer API - `Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms API`.

Help would be appreciated as it's not showing the parameters in my report. Only the toolbar is enabled.

```
                    rptViewer.ProcessingMode = rs.ProcessingMode.Local;
                    rptViewer.ShowParameterPrompts = true;
                    rptViewer.ShowToolBar = true;
                    rptViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = physicalReportPath;
```

[image]